# Closing jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

For some reason I have this code to be showed like a popup.

```
<div id="myDialog" title="myTitle">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <div class="message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell" onclick="doMyThing(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
    <span style="cursor:pointer">Accept</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I fire some event with Javascript, the next code is executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDialog').dialog();
    $('.message').html("Some text");
});
```

This is working just fine. Although, I need to hide/close the dialog after clicking on my span field. I've tried something like `$('#myDialog').dialog('close');` but it's not working. Also, tried to make in 'myDialog' `display: block` when first click and then `display: none`, but the dialog keeps on the screen anyway.

This 'myDialog' is actually receiving some style from css, that's why I'm coding a fake dialog like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you bind the click to fire the close event?

Comment: try applying `display:none` to its parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally used the jQuery buttons and changed its appearance. I was trying to use a css class there, but it didn't worked out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.message').html("Some text");
            $( '#myDialog' ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    'accept': {
                        style:'background:#D1040E; color: #DADADA',
                        text: 'Accept',
                        click: function() {
                            doMyThing(<?php echo $id; ?>);
                            $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                        }
                    },
                    'cancel': {
                        style:'background:#D1040E; color: #DADADA',
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        click: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the provided buttons instead of making your own

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#mydialog" ).dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
         "Accept": function() {
              doMyThing(<?= $id ?>);
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
       }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog" title="myTitle">
 <div class="table_cell">
  <div class="message"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can check proper documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Link Here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.dialog('close')` should work fine. Reference the span properly.

```
<div id="myDialog" title="myTitle">
  <div class="table_cell">
    <div class="message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_cell" onclick="doMyThing(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
    <span id='accept' style="cursor:pointer">Accept</span>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDialog').dialog();
    $('.message').html("Some text");
    $('#accept').on('click', function(){
         $('#myDialog').dialog('close');
    })
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2fzumdLx/)**